# jest for async functions

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am testing code that includes async functions. Even when testing a flow that doesn't use await, the test fails. When I remove async/await (which is possible, since the tested flow doesn't require it), the test passes.

I have built a simplified example of the code and the test.

(1) Example for code that is using async/await (although there is no need for that, as in my tested flow):

```
import React from 'react'

export class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { first: false }

  async func1 () {
    const selection = await this.func2()
    this.setState({ first: selection })
  }

  async func2 () {
    return true
  }

  render () {
    return null
  }
}
```

(2) The same code without async/await:

```
import React from 'react'

export class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { first: false }

  func1 () {
    const selection = this.func2()
    this.setState({ first: selection })
  }

  func2 () {
    return true
  }

  render () {
    return null
  }
}
```

And this is the test that fails (the third `expect` fails) for (1) and passes for (2). Any idea why and how to write the test so that the works for the code with async/await?

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Example } from '../../src/scenes/Recommendation/Patterns/Example'

let wrapper

describe('Testing Example', () => {
  it('calls func1 properly', async () => {
    wrapper = shallow(
      <Example />
    )
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    const prevState = { first: false }
    const expectedState = { first: true }

    expect.assertions(2)
    expect(instance.state).toEqual(prevState)
    await instance.func1()
    expect(instance.state).toEqual(expectedState)
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the error, the test passes with both versions of `Example` in my environment.

Comment: Strange... May be a setup problem, then.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify on which expectation your tests fails? Is it with the first expect or the second?

One thing that I can think of is that since jest naturally tests functions synchronously, if you have async code in the functions you are testing, they will occur after the call stack at the end of your test function. Instead you will need to add

```
expect.assertions(2);
```

at the beginning of your test functions so it waits for the async functions to finish running.

Comment: The second expect fails.
I tried also with expect.assertions(2), doesn't help (added it to the example now).

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157#issuecomment-279171856) problem in which promises aren't flushed.

Try adding updating your test case to the following

```
describe('Testing Example', () => {
  function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
  }

  it('calls func1 properly', async () => {
    wrapper = shallow(
      <Example />
    )
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    const prevState = { first: false }
    const expectedState = { first: true }

    expect.assertions(2)
    expect(instance.state).toEqual(prevState)
    await instance.func1()
    await flushPromises();
    expect(instance.state).toEqual(expectedState)
  })
});
```